Could this question be salvaged? If so, how?
The question Are MSSQL window functions logically redundant? got closed, because it "needs more focus".
Is the question completely unsalvageable (since this stack is about practical problems and the question seem more like idle intellectual exercise)?
Or is there something OP could do to get it reopened?

It's not a great question even after eight (minor) edits.
At different times, it has been (implicitly) about any database system (revisions 1 & 2), about Postgres (revisions 3 & 4), or Microsoft SQL Server (revisions 5-8). The first vote to close occurred just after revision 6 (adding sql-server).
The question is also very short:

Are there any SQL queries that can be done with window functions but not with JOIN operations?

This might sound like asking for some unbounded list of examples and exceptions.

Which window functions? All of them?

Does proving they're redundant require providing exactly equivalent join syntax for every possible original?

Does negating the proposition require proving a particular window function usage cannot be written with a join?


None of these problems are insoluble, but I don't blame the close voters.
The question completed reopen review and was not reopened.
It has now been automatically deleted.

An example of a conceptually similar question asked on Computer Science, which was well-received:
Do subqueries add expressive power to SQL queries?
Comparing and contrasting may be of assistance.

Thank you, Paul.

I won't edit the question because all the three points @paul-white mentioned are answerable from the question itself, as he said as well. In fact the question could easily be translated in mathematical notation.
The fact that the question has been reviewed (contradictorily, in the case of the DBMS) 8 times shouldn't matter, because there are no answers or comments which are DBMS-specific. I guarantee the DBMS won't change from now on.
Remember that the purpose of answering a question (which might or might not be  rooted in a real contingency, why should it matter?) is not only to answer a urgency of the creator, but to provide a service to the whole community.
The lack of examples might make the question lazy, but not unfocused.
